# JNI_CreateJavaVM() in Android

Tags: android-ndk

There are 2 ways to make Android native C/C++ to call Java code.

1. Java app calls the native functions first. The native functions save the JavaVM and JNIEnv, and then use them to call Java code, say Java class X.
2. The native functions call the same Java class X. In this case, we need a JVM to run the Java code. JNI_CreateJavaVM() can be used to do it.

I find the JVMs created by the above 2 ways are different.

Here is the Java class X.

```
public class X
{
    public X()
    {
        Log.d("X", "X()");
    }
}
```

The Log.d() can be run successfully in the way 1. However, in the way 2 I get the following error message from logcat:
"No implemention found for native Landroid/util/Log;.println_native(IILjava/lang/String;java/lang/String;)I"

I am thinking the JNIEnv got from JNI_CreateJavaVM() misses something. How could I solve the problem if I have to use the way 2?

Comment: How are you using JNI_CreateJavaVM function on Android at all? Android environment (jni.h header and libraries it provide) doesn't implement this function.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#wp9502

follow the example there.

Comment: Those are JavaSE docs. But we are talking about Android NDK, right? Open jni.h header from Android NDK and check yourself, that `JNI_CreateJavaVM` function is commented out.

Comment: I checked dalvik/libnativehelper/include/nativehelper/jni.h and prebuilt/ndk/android-ndk-r6/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h. Both have it defined as this:
------------------------------------------------------------
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * VM initialization functions.
 *
 * Note these are the only symbols exported for JNI by the VM.
 */
jint JNI_GetDefaultJavaVMInitArgs(void*);
jint JNI_CreateJavaVM(JavaVM**, JNIEnv**, void*);
jint JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs(JavaVM**, jsize, jsize*);
--------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: I'm not sure what are you looking at. Fragment of jni.h file from Android NDK looks like this: http://pastebin.com/yA7d1ie9 As you see - function is in "#if 0". Also it is not exported by any .so or .a file under libs folder.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the code in com.android.internal.util.WithFramework can help you.
See my similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13000561/cli-on-dalvikvm-fails-on-jni-lib)