# CLI on DalvikVM fails on JNI lib

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, dalvik

I need to run a command line version of java application on Android(Yeah I know it's not trivial).

I'm trying to start it using Dalvikvm, it actually starts but somewhere later my code fails because it starts using android.util.log and throws this exception.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: println_native
    at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
    at android.util.Log.i(Log.java:159)
    at org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLogger.info(AndroidLogger.java:151)
    at org.gihon.client.TunnelingClient.<init>(TunnelingClient.java:62)
    at org.gihon.client.CLI.main(CLI.java:95)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I tried setting the environment variables, I set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH and the BOOTCLASSPATH variables. I even tried preloading liblog with LD_PRELOAD but nothing fixed that.
It seems that something is wrong/different with the way dalvikvm sets the environment.

Comment: What's the command you used to start it ... start there.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Good question! I had to dig a bit to figure this out.

There are a slew of JNI methods in libandroid_runtime.so that don't get bound by default, when you're using the dalvikvm command. Unfortunately, you can't just do a System.loadLibrary("android_runtime"), because this doesn't actually bind all the native methods.

However, after some digging, it turns out there is an internal, non-public, not guaranteed to be there class called com.android.internal.util.WithFramework, whose purpose is to load libandroid_runtime.so and bind all its JNI methods.

To use it, just throw `com.android.internal.util.WithFramework` in front of your class name, on the dalvikvm command, like so:

```
dalvikvm -cp /some/path/classes.dex com.android.internal.util.WithFramework my.example.cls "This is an argument"
```

(Note: This only works on pre-M devices, due to the WithFramework class being [removed in M](https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/157981/) - thanks for the heads up @JaredRummler)

Comment: I guess I was lucky enough to have WithFramework on my device and it works.

Comment: Yeah, it's almost certainly there on all devices. But it's not guaranteed to be there, and may go away/change in the future. (like any non-public api)

Comment: `System.load("/system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so");` ?

Comment: @AwaisKing there's a question mark there, but I'm not seeing a question?

Comment: @JesusFreke sorry, can we use it? `System.load("/system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so");` instead of `System.loadLibrary("android_runtime")` ?

Comment: Is there some reason you can't use the approach I outlined in my answer?

Comment: It doesn't work on my both device **4.4** and **4.2**.
It returns `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`

Comment: @AwaisKing feel free to ask an actual question. You probably want to reference this question, and add some details about your particular failure. Feel free to ping me in the question, to make sure I see it.

Comment: @JesusFreke nvm, I cancelled that project.
Thanks anyway :)

Comment: `com.android.internal.util.WithFramework` will be removed in Android M. https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/157981/

Comment: Has there been any other solutions to this since com.android.internal.util.WithFramework was removed?

Answer (score 6):

For android M, I found this method to work.
Create a helloworld.sh script to accompany your jar\zip file:

```
#!/system/bin/sh
# Copied by example from am command
base=/system
export CLASSPATH=/path/to/your/jar/HelloWorld.jar
exec app_process $base/bin HelloWorldMainClass "$@"
```

[app_process](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-6.0.1_r3/cmds/app_process/app_main.cpp) seems to start your java code with all java classes and shared libs loaded, so you can use both SDK classes like android.util.log.Log AND "secret" native classes, e.g. ActivityManagerNative, that are used in other adb shell commands, and are not present in the SDK.

BTW, for the java shell command I created, I had to resort to using reflection for the above classes, because it seems to me there is no way to compile properly without cloning and building the entire AOSP...

If someone knows an easier way to e.g. use ActivityManagerNative in java code without reflection, I'd appreciate the help.

Comment: To answer my own question: you can create stub implementations for the classes and methods you know you'll be using, and compile against them

Comment: app_process require root access to the device while dalvikvm does not

Comment: OK? Seeing as most users will run this using adb shell, it didn't seem like a big problem to me. If it's a problem for you, you certainly can try to run dalvikvm directly. If you have an easy way to do it, please post it here.

Comment: I think a possible solution would be to try to understand and manage a way to use the System.load of all that is needed. Easier said than done though.

Comment: Tolstoyevsky, actually your answer works at least on devices running android Oreo (and above). You don't need root. A few configuration based on the time of android shell maybe needed like exporting the ANDROID_DATA and/or setting up path and LD_LIBRARY_PATH