# Android, ADB Command-line tool in Java

Tags: android, android-ndk, adb, dalvik

---

I need my code to run under the "shell" account.

Is it possible to implement an ADB Command-Line tool using Java ( and not only C++ ) ?

Is there a C++ API enabling to manually load JVM ?

any pointers/examples would be appreciated.

Comment: Executing code developed in the Java programming language is easy; see e.g. http://milk.com/kodebase/dalvik-docs-mirror/docs/hello-world.html for a trivial example.  I assume from your other questions that you want it to interact with the Android app framework?

Comment: Yeah exactly, I want to be able to 'getDefaultDisplay()'@Java while running under the 'shell' account.

Comment: Once again with the non-public stuff: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13000561/cli-on-dalvikvm-fails-on-jni-lib