# Android BinderInternal.getContextObject:()Landroid/os/IBinder running app via adb

Tags: android, dalvik

I am trying to run a java app via adb using `dalvikvm -cp`. It works in case of simple apps, but as soon as I want to use android native classes, e.g. do this (and include the android.jar in the classpath of javac to handle dependencies):

```
import android.view.KeyCharacterMap;
...
KeyCharacterMap kcm = KeyCharacterMap.load(KeyCharacterMap.VIRTUAL_KEYBOARD);
```

and run the app from adb using `dalvikvm -cp` I get this error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.android.internal.os.BinderInternal.getContextObject:()Landroid/os/IBinder;
        at com.android.internal.os.BinderInternal.getContextObject(Native Method)
        at android.os.ServiceManager.getIServiceManager(ServiceManager.java:39)
        at android.os.ServiceManager.getService(ServiceManager.java:55)
        at android.hardware.input.InputManager.getInstance(InputManager.java:187)
        at android.view.KeyCharacterMap.load(KeyCharacterMap.java:331)
```

And in logcat:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.android.internal.os.BinderInternal.getContextObject:()Landroid/os/IBinder;
        at com.android.internal.os.BinderInternal.getContextObject(Native Method)
        at android.os.ServiceManager.getIServiceManager(ServiceManager.java:39)
        at android.os.ServiceManager.getService(ServiceManager.java:55)
        at android.hardware.input.InputManager.getInstance(InputManager.java:187)
        at android.view.KeyCharacterMap.load(KeyCharacterMap.java:331)
W/dalvikvm(22137): No implementation found for native Lcom/android/internal/os/BinderInternal;.getContextObject:()Landroid/os/IBinder;
W/dalvikvm(22137): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4092f2a0)
D/dalvikvm(22137): GC_CONCURRENT freed 19K, 89% free 118K/1024K, paused 0ms+0ms, total 1ms
W/dalvikvm(22137): No implementation found for native Lcom/android/internal/os/BinderInternal;.handleGc:()V
E/System  (22137): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer
E/System  (22137): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.android.internal.os.BinderInternal.handleGc:()V
E/System  (22137):      at com.android.internal.os.BinderInternal.handleGc(Native Method)
E/System  (22137):      at com.android.internal.os.BinderInternal$GcWatcher.finalize(BinderInternal.java:45)
E/System  (22137):      at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:186)
E/System  (22137):      at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:169)
E/System  (22137):      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

I looked at sources of apps such as `am` or `input` and they successfully use binding, so what should I do to use it in my adb java app?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13000561/cli-on-dalvikvm-fails-on-jni-lib :)