# Android / Dalvik VM Cannot Find Native Framework Methods

Tags: java, android, dalvik

I am trying something a little unconventional so I am not surprised that I am encountering difficulties.

I want to use an Ubuntu `chroot` on an Android tablet as a UNIX CLI IDE for various kinds of software development. Since I am working on an Android device, I was curious if I could build Android code against the SDK, `dx` (Dalvik eXchange compiler) the compiled bytecode, copy out to the sdcard, and execute with `dalvikvm`.

A 'hello world' test (with no Android API) worked fine but the handful of Android API calls I've tried failed with `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError`. The calls into the API that I have tried seem to call down to (presumably JNI) native methods that Dalvik cannot find at runtime:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for boolean android.os.SystemProperties.native_get_boolean(java.lang.String, boolean) (tried Java_android_os_SystemProperties_native_1get_1boolean and Java_android_os_SystemProperties_native_1get_1boolean__Ljava_lang_String_2Z)
        at android.os.SystemProperties.native_get_boolean(Native Method)
        at android.os.SystemProperties.getBoolean(SystemProperties.java:114)
        at android.text.TextUtils.<clinit>(TextUtils.java:1919)
        at android.media.AudioAttributes$Builder.build(AudioAttributes.java:337)
        at android.media.AudioRecord.<init>(AudioRecord.java:233)
        at AltTest.main(alttest.java:34)
```

---

For a concrete example, I tried the following code as, say, `test.java`:

```
import android.media.AudioRecord;

class APITest {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println("Hello, world!");

  // compiles, 'dx'ifies, and runs up this this point
  int apiMinimumBufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(44100,16,2);

  System.out.println("Your audio sample buffer must be at least " + apiMinimumBufferSize + " bytes.");
 }

}
```

Compiled to `APITest.class` with the following:

```
root@localhost:~/projects/test# CLASSPATH=/root/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-21/android.jar javac test.java
```

`dx`ified:

```
root@localhost:~/projects/test# /root/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/25.0.0/dx --dex --output=test.dex APITest.class
```

Note that we would not expect APITest.class to execute in the `chroot` java environment due to the `android.jar` dependency:

```
root@localhost:~/projects/test# java -cp ".:/root/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-21/android.jar" APITest
Hello, world!
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
        at android.media.AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(AudioRecord.java:21)
        at APITest.main(test.java:9)
```

But, if we place a copy of the `dx`ified build where we can see it from the non-`chroot`ed android environment:

```
root@localhost:~/projects/test# cp test.dex /mnt/android_root/sdcard
```

Then we can attempt to execute the code in `dalvikvm` on a running Android machine:

```
[non-root-user]@[product_ID]:/ # su
root@[product_ID]:/ # cd sdcard
root@[product_ID]:/sdcard # dalvikvm -cp test.dex APITest
Hello, world!
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for int android.media.AudioRecord.native_get_min_buff_size(int, int, int) (tried Java_android_media_AudioRecord_native_1get_1min_1buff_1size and Java_android_media_AudioRecord_native_1get_1min_1buff_1size__III)
        at android.media.AudioRecord.native_get_min_buff_size(Native Method)
        at android.media.AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(AudioRecord.java:592)
        at APITest.main(test.java:9)
```

---

I have scanned all the `lib*.so` files in the native android filesystem (e.g. '/system/lib' and '/vendor/lib') for dynamic symbols that look like the method names that `dalvikvm` was looking for and other possible "DLL entry points" based on my vague knowledge of JNI. I don't know exactly what I am looking for. So far, I have only found a random scattering of potentially related methods.

I have tried running `dalvikvm` under `strace` (which I carefully liberated from my `chroot` so I could run it against shell commands in the native Android environment). My read of the system-call traffic was that, other than reading many of the libs in `/system/vendor`, `dalvikvm` gave little hint regarding where it would have expected those native implementations to be.

One idea I had was to figure out how to make `dalvikvm` tell me where it found a native implementation. Using `Ruboto IRB`, one may call Android API methods and many of these call through to native implementations. If there were available introspection in Dalvik and I knew how to call on it, or if I knew how to attach debugging equipment to a running process that has been activated by the Android GUI, or if I knew how to invoke Android GUI apps from the CLI presented by the `Terminal Emulator` app, I could imagine trying something like that.

I have also imagined disassembling a working app to study the interrelationships between the parts and attempt to back-out build or run-time requirements for practical Dalvik code in the Android ecosystem.

Most of my ideas are a bit "blue sky", heading off into an open research question from a position of ignorance. I'm sure I would learn a lot but it might take me a long time to find a way to move forward.

And, so, I'm hoping that someone with relevant experience might have the grace to tell me what they know about the mistakes I am making and how to fix them.

---

So, to get some Android code running from the terminal:

What am I missing from the ad-hoc build process detailed above?

Or, what am I missing from the execution context at run-time?

---

Thanks!

Comment: It may help to know which device/OS version you are testing against.

Comment: @morrison-chang: An RCA Viking Pro 10.1 running Android 5.0, rooted but otherwise stock

Comment: So Android 5.0 was the first version where ART was the default - I assume you are aware of this page http://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/configure.html note the link to the Google IO video on ART as well.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13000561/cli-on-dalvikvm-fails-on-jni-lib for a possible solution

Comment: Note that my answer on that question only works on pre-M devices, but there's another solution for M+ (although I can't personally vouch for that solution - I haven't tried it)

Comment: @JesusFreke: what is the correct way to credit you with a working answer to my question? I bumped in to some of your work while I was stumbling around this problem. I even looked at `smali` at a candidate tool to reverse-engineer working Android API/SDK code. It feels like a kind of irony that it was you who solved this problem and that you did it four years ago.

Goes to show that best efforts to google and search SO history will sometimes leave stones unturned. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @MorrisonChang: your reference re: ART pulled-back another curtain for me. I am not really an Android dev IRL so the Android-SDK extension of my "cheap mobile dev platform" experiment was mostly a whimsical dream constructed from the fading edges of misfired google searches. Thank you for the note.

Comment: @Jsnydr: Feel free to upvote my answer on that question, if you like. I'll go ahead and put in a close vote for this one as a duplicate of that question.