# UnsatisfiedLinkError on dalvikvm from AudioTrack

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, dalvik, audiotrack

So I am messing around with AudioTrack on `dalvikvm` (I did it on `app_process` as well which is another story):

```
$ cat android/media/Hello.java
package android.media;

class Hello
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        AudioAttributes aa = new AudioAttributes.Builder().build();
        AudioFormat af = new AudioFormat.Builder().build();
        AudioTrack at = new AudioTrack(aa, af, 4, 1, 0);
        at.release();
    }
}
$
```

And I get:

```
$ /system/bin/dalvikvm -cp android.dex android.media.Hello
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for int android.media.AudioTrack.native_get_FCC_8() (tried Java_android_media_AudioTrack_native_1get_1FCC_18 and Java_android_media_AudioTrack_native_1get_1FCC_18__)
        at android.media.AudioTrack.native_get_FCC_8(Native Method)
        at android.media.AudioTrack.<clinit>(AudioTrack.java:99)
        at android.media.Hello.main(Hello.java:9)
$
```

Then I created these:

```
$ cat media/AudioTrack.java
package media;

public class AudioTrack
{
    public static final int CHANNEL_COUNT_MAX = native_get_FCC_8();
    public AudioTrack() {
        System.out.printf("%d\n", CHANNEL_COUNT_MAX);
    }
    static private native int native_get_FCC_8();
}
$ cat media/Hello.java
package media;

class Hello
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new AudioTrack();
    }
}
$
```

Which allows me to get similar error, as I desired:

```
$ /system/bin/dalvikvm -cp media.dex media.Hello
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for int media.AudioTrack.native_get_FCC_8() (tried Java_media_AudioTrack_native_1get_1FCC_18 and Java_media_AudioTrack_native_1get_1FCC_18__)
        at media.AudioTrack.native_get_FCC_8(Native Method)
        at media.AudioTrack.<clinit>(AudioTrack.java:5)
        at media.Hello.main(Hello.java:7)
$
```

Then I created this:

```
$ cat fcc.c
#include <jni.h>

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_media_AudioTrack_native_1get_1FCC_18(JNIEnv *, jobject);

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_android_media_AudioTrack_native_1get_1FCC_18(JNIEnv *, jobject);

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_media_AudioTrack_native_1get_1FCC_18(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
{
  return 8;
}

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_android_media_AudioTrack_native_1get_1FCC_18(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
{
  return 8;
}
$
```

And compiled it to a shared library named `libfcc.so`.

Then I added:

```
    static
    {
        System.loadLibrary("fcc");
    }
```

to the beginning of both `Hello` (just before `main`) and recompiled all the java files.

Yet it only works with media.AudioTrack (the fake one), but not android.media.AudioTrack (the real one):

```
$ /system/bin/dalvikvm -Djava.library.path=. -cp media.dex media.Hello
8
$ /system/bin/dalvikvm -Djava.library.path=. -cp android.dex android.media.Hello
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for int android.media.AudioTrack.native_get_FCC_8() (tried Java_android_media_AudioTrack_native_1get_1FCC_18 and Java_android_media_AudioTrack_native_1get_1FCC_18__)
        at android.media.AudioTrack.native_get_FCC_8(Native Method)
        at android.media.AudioTrack.<clinit>(AudioTrack.java:99)
        at android.media.Hello.main(Hello.java:13)
$
```

Anyone knows why?

Comment: See my answer here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13000561/cli-on-dalvikvm-fails-on-jni-lib  - although, I think recent versions of android (N+? maybe?) no longer include the WithFramework class, unfortunately

Comment: @JesusFreke I am on Android O, but anyway I think I am more interested in *why* `LoadLibrary` doesn't work for the Android classes (like in term of Java, if you know what I mean), coz I don't really *need* it to work on `dalvikvm`. Thanks though.

Comment: I can't answer directly, but I would recommend looking at the implementation of WithFramework class, and it's corresponding native code :)

Comment: fwiw, you might be able to use the app_process binary to start your command, which should have all of the android jni linked in. See, e.g. Tolstoyevsky's answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13000561/cli-on-dalvikvm-fails-on-jni-lib